How to prevent my window from gaining input focus?
I am implementing an AutoComplete, but one that will match text anywhere in the list of enumerated strings—rather than just the beginning of a suggestion as is the behavior of the built-in SHAutoComplete control
For example:

The "popup" window is a TForm that must:

set CS_DROPSHADOW style during CreateParams (subject to checking SPI_GETDROPSHADOW of course; I'm not a heathen who doesn't pay his taxes)
Params.WindowClass.Style := Params.WindowClass.Style or CS_DROPSHADOW;


and of course set its WndParent to the form that holds the TEdit (so that the drop-down appears on top of the form it's popping up over)
Params.WndParent := FWndParent;



I have the Up, Down, Return, Escape keyboard navigation working fine. The typist can quickly select the item they want, and the list of suggestions closes.
The form contains a TListView for the actual items (much like CAutoComplete SHAutoComplete class does in Windows).
Clicking takes focus
If the user clicks an item in the drop-down, then using Inspect (the accessiblity tool in the SDK) we can see that focus was given to one of the listitems in the (now hidden) drop-down menu:

You can even see the title-bar indicates that the entire window on no longer has focus.
How can I prevent my window from obtaining input focus?
Attempts
Return MA_NOACTIVATE
I tried responding to the WM_MOUSEACTIVATE window message and return MA_NOACTIVATE:



Return code/value
Description




MA_ACTIVATE (1)
Activates the window, and does not discard the mouse message.


MA_ACTIVATEANDEAT (2)
Activates the window, and discards the mouse message.


MA_NOACTIVATE (3)
Does not activate the window, and does not discard the mouse message.


MA_NOACTIVATEANDEAT (4)
Does not activate the window, but discards the mouse message.



Such as:
procedure TfrmAutoComplete.WMMouseActivate(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
    inherited;
    Msg.Result := MA_NOACTIVATE;
end;

But it still gets focus.
SetFocus during WM_ACTIVATE
I tried messing with things that ought not be messed with, and calling SetFocus during WM_ACTIVATE:
procedure TfrmAutoComplete.WMActivate(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
    inherited;
    Msg.Result := MA_NOACTIVATE;

    Windows.SetFocus(FEdit.Handle);
end;

Raymond Chens talks about why this is a bad idea; although i must confess i don't understand:

The dangers of messing with activation when handling a WM_ACTIVATE message
Raymond Chen, August 9th, 2005
This is basically the same thing as The dangers of playing focus games when handling a WM_KILLFOCUS message, just with activation in place of focus. One developer discovered the hard way that if you mess with activation inside your WM_ACTIVATE handler, things get weird. The author noted that if he posted a message and did the work from the posted message, then everything came out okay.
A follow-up to the original message noted that passing the SWP_NOACTIVATE flag to the SetWindowPos function solves the problem. Do you understand why?

And, of course, when the TEdit loses focus, it hides the suggestion drop-down. So there's probably a focus lock-out race going on.
Short Version
Is there a better way?
Bonus Reading (aka Research Effort)

Preventing a window from gaining focus automatically (using Windows API)
Notification Window - Preventing the window from ever getting focus


Have you checked How to simulate drop-down form in Delphi?. From what I see that question pretty much covers your goal.

In win32, just set the extended style of the window and refer to WS_EX_NOACTIVATE. SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_NOACTIVATE);

Why reinvent the wheel instead of just providing your own autocomplete source (see How to Enable Autocomplete Manually)?

@IInspectable I did provide my own autocomplete source (see the screenshot in the question). You can see in the question why that doesn't solve my problem.

@SilverWarior Yes, since it's my question, i know it well. Unfortunately it doesn't cover my goal. Getting focus to work correctly in Windows is voodoo nightmare of untold proportions. I've been dealing with one unfixable focus bug since c. 2003

@Torrecto-MSFT Do i have to set that to all 3 windows that make up the drop-down? Can i set it on just the top-level window; or will that not work? Can i set it only on the window that covers the entire popup client area; or will that not work?

I'm not sure where in the screenshot I am supposed to see that you have implemented a custom autocomplete source. I also don't know where the question explains why that wouldn't work. You can configure an edit control to always display the full list of autocomplete suggestions, which is under your control.

The solution is roughly this: 1 Implement a custom autocomplete source, a COM object that needs to implement the IEnumString interface. 2 Instantiate a CLSID_AutoComplete object. 3 Navigate to the IAutoComplete2 interface and call SetOptions() with a value that includes ACO_NOPREFIXFILTERING. 4 Init() the edit control from this IAutoComplete interface, passing your custom source along.

Net result: All windowing aspects are handled for you, and the edit control doesn't apply any filtering to the candidate list you supply. Your custom source (which is under your full control) now only needs to produce a candidate list in response to EN_CHANGEs. Filtering is completely arbitrary and under your full control.

@IInspectable Have you tried it? I have a string in my IEnumString containing "Therapist". I type rapist in the edit box, and Therapist does not appear as a suggestion. In fact, adding ACO_NOPREFIXFILTERING causes ALL items to always be a suggestion.

Which makes sense that ACO_NOPREFIXFILTERING seems to disable any meaningful suggestions, as the doucmentation says, "Disable prefix filtering when displaying the autosuggest dropdown. Always display all suggestions." When i'm trying to show matching suggestions, i don't see how passing ACO_NOPREFIXFILTERING can be useful - as it does the opposite of show matching suggestions. Are you thinking of another flag that performs the moral equivalent of *text* searching for suggestions?

By default, IAutoComplete takes a list of candidates to produce a list of suggestions. It supports several filtering schemes, but all of them are prefix-based. Turning off filtering effectively promotes the list of candidates to the list of suggestions. All you need to do is keep the custom source consistent with UI input by implementing the filtering in your source.

@IInspectable Have you tried your suggestion? If i dynamically update the IEnumString behind the IAutoComplete's back while it is still showing suggestions: it still only matches items in the original list (i.e. it does not dynamically recognize the list has changed). If i call IAutoComplete.Init to give it the updated list every time the user changes text in the text box: it still doesn't update the list as the user types.

@IInspectable If i instead disable the autocomplete (IAutoComplete.Enable(False)), then update the IEnumString, then re-enable the autocomplete (IAutoComplete.Enable(True)), it still does not pickup the updated IEnumString; but instead continues to use a cached copy. If intead i call IAutoComplete.Init to give it a new IEnumString while it is showing, then it still does not pick up the new list of matching suggestions. Can you provide a working example?

@IInspectable Trying to re-create the AutoComplete in order to give it a list of matching text from the OnChange event of a TEdit, while the AutoComplete still has the TEdit subclassed causes an access violation from deep inside shell32. The autocomplete does not like being destroyed while its code is running.

@IInspectable: I have been following this discussion between you and Ian Boyd, and am genuinely curious: What do you think about Ian's latest reply? Have you successfully used the Win32 autocomplete system to filter on substrings (not only prefixes) yourself or seen it being used like that, or is it "just" an educated guess that it should be feasible? (I'm not trying to be arrogant or anything, I simply don't know if your proposed approach has actually been tested in practice or not.)

@IInspectable: Immediately after having posted my last comment, I recalled that I myself have been using the Win32 autocomplete facilities in a few apps. I just now started one of them and can clearly see that the autocomplete system in this app actually does filter on substrings, not only prefix substrings. So I just answered my own question: Yes, the Win32 autocomplete facilities can certainly be used for substring (not necessarily prefix) filtering/searching.

@IanBoyd: It turns out that some of my own applications do use the Win32 autocomplete facilities and that they do filter/search for substrings (not necessarily prefixes), so clearly the Win32 facilities can be used for this, as IInspectable has already stated.

@AndreasRejbrand If you have a working solution i would LOVE to hear it. I'm on day 4 of trying to make this work correctly. I'm about to just translate the CAutoComplete.cpp from the Windows XP source to Delphi: mouse hooks, edit control subclassing, and custom listview drawing and all.

@IanBoyd: You are very unlucky. The app in question is one I wrote for my company, and I am on out of office since today and for the next three weeks...

@AndreasRejbrand Might you be able to post your CMRE to allow the use of the shell Auto complete?

procedure TfrmAutoComplete.WMActivate(var Msg: TWMActivate);
begin
  inherited;

  if Msg.Active = 0 then
  begin
    if Visible then
    begin
      Hide;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    SendMessage(FWndParent, WM_NCACTIVATE, 1, 0);
  end;
end;


Please read [answer].
